# CGI file location for xampp on windows

Tags: perl, cgi, xampp

I am using XAMPP 1.7.2 on winxp. 
I plan to dev web app (.cgi or .pl) and I checked phpinfo() and found mod_perl already enabled.

But I tried to place my hello.cgi file in `C:\xampp\htdocs\hello.cgi` or `C:\xampp\cgi-bin\hello.cgi`. Both methods won't work when I try to open **http://localhost/hello.cgi**

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The location will be

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.cgi
```

The place you should be putting your .cgi scripts is in the cgi-bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions, since your hello.cgi program won't work in either the htdocs or cgi-bin directories:

1) Examine the Apache error log file, to see if the script is indeed getting executed, and you're receiving some other kind of error.

2) Examine the Apache httpd.conf, for the [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler) and the [ScriptAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) settings. These dictate what files should be run as scripts, and what directory contains CGI scripts.

XAMPP is a good package for learning the LAMP stack on Windows XP. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Name it `/perl/` not `/cgi-bin/`.